# How can I find the host machine network ip address on travis?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

Sorry for the naive question but I am new to using travis and read the docs thoroughly but I can't figure out what exactly I need to put in my `.travis.yml` or use as an IP address.

I have setup my server on local host in travis. For client testing I need the ip address of the local host to test my client app.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
language: generic
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - net-tools
script:
  - /sbin/ifconfig
```

That installs the `net-tools` package, then calls the `ifconfig` command that package adds.

In the output from that command, you want to look at the information for the `eth0` interface:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:08  
          inet addr:172.17.0.8  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1083 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:17000256 (17.0 MB)  TX bytes:122513 (122.5 KB)
```

But it’s better these days to instead use the `ip` command from the `iproute2` package:

```
dist: trusty
language: generic
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - iproute2
script:
  - ip a
```

Sample output:

```
10: eth0@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.5/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just to be sure, I get 3 outputs when I try it in travis `lo:`, `eth0:` and `docker0:`. Can you please clarify which one to use?

Comment: You can ignore the `lo:` part. Normally you want just the `eth0:` part. The `docker0:` part only shows up because you’re using docker, but in that case I don’t see that it could change the IP address, so I would think you could ignore whatever it says, and just use the IP address the `eth0:` part shows.

Comment: I updated my answer to explicitly say the information shown for the `eth0` interface is the part to look at.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am now trying to write a script to get the inet in variable and use it to modify one of my files.

Comment: by the way, I am getting a range of ip addreses `10.10.11.205/32`, any idea which one to use? Thanks!

Comment: In `ip a` output, the part after the slash is just indicating the prefix length and can big ignored in this case.